# Running PHP script in loop with Supervisor

Tags: php, background-process, supervisord

I'm having problems running PHP script in loop with Supervisor. I have PHP script that can be called from command line with `php myscript.php` and corresponding `supervisord.conf` which is:

```
[program:queuereceiver]
command=/var/www/app/myscript.php
directory=/var/www/app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=0
startretries=3
user=www-data
stdout_logfile=/var/www/app/logs/queue_out.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile=/var/www/app/logs/queue_err.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
```

This simply runs script as process and when it's finished (mostly less than 1 second) runs it again in loop.

The thing is from time to time this `queuereceiver` simply stops running without any error being put to `queue_err.log`.

If you had similar cases – any ideas why it's happening or even how to debug it? As you probably notices this PHP script receives messages from queue.

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty).

Comment: Is the queue_err.log where all your PHP error would go or is that another log file? If it is for PHP errors and you do no see anything you might want to look at the sys logs for the OS. Your process might be colliding with other OS processes.

Comment: Yes, queue_err.log is log for PHP errors. Syslog then? I'll check.